# Scaling fragment height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is probably something real simple but buggered if I can solve.

I'm trying to create a login page similar to Evernotes using a tabbed layout with login and signup fragments (fixed height textview top half of screen and login/sign-in fragments bottom half).

However the fragments appear to be the same size as parent and the textview is shifting the fragment down and partially off-screen i.e when I use a textview with **layout_alignParentBottom="true"** this textview is off screen?.

Any ideas?

heres my layout XML:

Main activity ()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_login_signup" />

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iv_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Feature Graphic Here!"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_test"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my login fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="activity.LoginFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Top"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_login"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bottom"<-- this is pushed down off screen-->
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, view pager should have been inside the appbarlayout body! working a charm now.